# How to call the function glMultiDrawElements :: GLenum -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr GLsizei -> GLenum -> GHC.Ptr.Ptr (GHC.Ptr.Ptr a) -> GLsizei -> IO ()

Tags: c, opengl, haskell, ffi

The ffunction `glMultiDrawElements` requires a pointer to a pointer as one of its arguments. How might one obtain a `Ptr(Ptr a)` from a StorableArray Int `a` ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to first marshal your lists of indices into `Ptr`'s, then marshal those `Ptr`'s into a `Ptr (Ptr Int))`

You can do something like this

```
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

indices :: [[Int]]

do
  ixPtrs <- mapM newArray indices
  sizes  <- newArray $ map (fromIntegral . length) indices
  ixPtrPtr <- newArray ixPtrs
  glMultiDrawElements enumType sizes iType ixPtrPtr (fromIntegral $ length indices)

  mapM_ free ixPtrs
  free ixPtrPtr
  free sizes
```

Here the list of `Ptr`s is still in scope, so we can mapM over it to free each pointer.  If you want to free the memory later, you can either retain the list or keep the ixPtrPtr and use `peekArray` to get the original pointers back.

Comment: This seems to be what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric: if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted".  It's helpful to us both.